# Home wifi wastage for nothing

Tags: iphone, wifi

My internet broadband package at home is limited to a volume of 40GB. Ever since I bought my iphone 6s, 40GB finishes within half the month. I have disable all auto downloads, auto update, iCloud backup over wifi; but yet my iPhone wastes about 3,5 gigabytes per day for nothong. I can't understand why. Longer I keep the phone connected to my home wifi connection the more my wifi internet volume drops. It doesn't happen over cellular data anyway, only when my phone is connected to home wifi. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure all the 3.5 daily GB are used from your iPhone? Have you got others devices connect to the network?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you say "3.5 gigabytes per day for nothing" why not just turn off WiFi on the phone? Perhaps you can edit this to have some more detail on what you are using to measure WiFi data usage and whether you can differentiate between other users of bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because I monitored this for hours continually checking my home broadband usage meter through my laptop while enabling and disabling iPhone's wifi. I also used an app named "My data mgr" to monitor wifi data usage over a given period of time.

Comment: Then I suggest to follow what @bmike tells you...

Comment: Hm there's no point in using this phone without wifi no. Is there a way which I can specifically monitor which App or which process consumes wifi data and in what amounts?

Comment: I did a settings reset. Didn't work.

Comment: Nalith - please make an edit to the post with the specific details in the comment - that will help someone know what tools and data you have collected :-)

Answer (score 1):

This article should help you greatly: http://www.wired.com/2015/10/a-new-ios-9-feature-is-eating-your-cellular-data/

There is also a list in settings that lists how much data various apps use.  It's most likely Mail or Messages using so much data for push notifications.  If you switch to a 5-minutely update rather than push, then you might have better results.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP here want to shift some of the broadband usage over to cellular usage? This is about eating WiFi data, not cellular data - no?

Comment: It's data.  Whether it goes out over WiFi or cellular is dependent on whether or not he is connected to WiFi.  I'm assuming the OP would rather terminate/reduce the usage rather than chew up his cell data.